# GPU temperature sensor dropping randomly

Tags: gpu, amd-radeon, temperature, speedfan

I have an AMD Radeon HD 6900 series graphics card, when not playing games the temperature will be reading anywhere from around 40c - 50c.

But when playing games, the correct reading of the temperature will be around 60c - 64c, but this reading will also drop randomly down to 20c - 30c before going back up to the correct reading.

I've tested this with CCC and Speedfan, both produce the same temperature values. I am using Speedfan to control my fan speeds and it's quite bothersome to hear my GPU fan spinning then stopping constantly.

I'm not sure whether this is a hardware issue, but a simple fix would be to just ignore sudden drops in the temperature (or ignore anything below 35c), but I don't think Speedfan has such a functionality?